# How do I setup Bitbucket pipeline for my PHP app on Google Cloud?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, bitbucket-pipelines

I've been trying to get bitbucket pipeline deploy to Google cloud php app. But I keep getting a missing python executable error.Here's the script I have to install Google cloud SDK:

```
image: php:7.1.3

pipelines:
default:
- step:
    caches:
      - composer
    script:
    # Downloading the Google Cloud SDK
      - curl -O -J https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
      - tar -xvf google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -C /tmp/
      - /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh -q
      - source /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
      - gcloud -v
```

And get's stuck with this error:

```
To use the Google Cloud SDK, you must have Python installed and on your PATH. As an alternative, you may also set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable
```

to the location of your Python executable.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are using a PHP image (Docker image), which obviously does not include Python. Therefore, you either have to find another image which includes PHP *and* Python, or build one yourself. Building your own can be as simple as what is described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45963743/4715679