# MongoMemoryServer - Instance failed to start because a library is missing or cannot be opened: "libcurl.so.4"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, pnpm

I'm writing an integration test using `jest`. The test was successfully run on my Mac. But it throws an error in Bitbucket pipelines. I'm using `pnpm` in Bitbucket pipelines.

The error is:

```
FAIL __tests__/integration/routes/signout.test.ts
  ● Console
    console.warn
      Starting the MongoMemoryServer Instance failed, enable debug log for more information. Error:
       StdoutInstanceError: Instance failed to start because a library is missing or cannot be opened: "libcurl.so.4"
          at MongoInstance.checkErrorInLine (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb-memory-server-core@8.14.0/node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/util/MongoInstance.ts:678:11)
          at MongoInstance.stderrHandler (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb-memory-server-core@8.14.0/node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/util/MongoInstance.ts:563:10)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
          at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
          at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
          at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
      at MongoMemoryServer.<anonymous> (node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb-memory-server-core@8.14.0/node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/MongoMemoryServer.ts:293:17)
      at node_modules/.pnpm/tslib@2.6.1/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:169:75
      at __awaiter (node_modules/.pnpm/tslib@2.6.1/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:165:16)
      at node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb-memory-server-core@8.14.0/node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/MongoMemoryServer.ts:284:68
  ● Signout › should clears the cookie when signing out
    Instance failed to start because a library is missing or cannot be opened: "libcurl.so.4"
      at MongoInstance.checkErrorInLine (node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb-memory-server-core@8.14.0/node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/util/MongoInstance.ts:678:11)
      at MongoInstance.stderrHandler (node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb-memory-server-core@8.14.0/node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/util/MongoInstance.ts:563:10)
```

The error message is:

```
Instance failed to start because a library is missing or cannot be opened: "libcurl.so.4"
```

The test code is:

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

let mongo: any;

beforeAll(async () => {
  process.env.JWT_KEY = "randomsafjlkfdsaauthkey";

  mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  const mongoUri = mongo.getUri();

  await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {});
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

  for (let collection of collections) {
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
});

afterAll(async () => {
  if (mongo) {
    await mongo.stop();
  }
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});

// TEST CASE from another file
describe("Signout", () => {
  it("should clears the cookie when signing out", async () => {
    await request(app)
      .post("/v2/auth/signup")
      .send({
        email: "test@test.com",
        password: "password",
      })
      .expect(201);

    const response = await request(app)
      .post("/v2/auth/signout")
      .send({})
      .expect(200);

    expect(response.get("Set-Cookie")[0]).toBe(
      "session=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; httponly"
    );
  });
});
```

`bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```yaml
definitions:
  caches:
    pnpm: $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/.pnpm-store

image: node:18-slim

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        script:
          - corepack enable
          - corepack prepare pnpm@latest-8 --activate
          - pnpm install
          - pnpm run test:ci
        caches:
          - pnpm
```

Node version: 18.17.1

Answer (score 0):

The `node:slim` image variant does not ship with non-essential packages https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node#nodeslim. Namely `libcurl4`.

Just use the regular more bloated `node:<version>` in your pipeline.

```yaml
image: node:18

# ...
```

---

Alternatively, install libcurl4 as part of your step setup.

```yaml
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:
    - &apt-install-script >-
        apt-get update
        && apt-get install --yes libcurl4

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        image: node:18-slim
        script:
          - *apt-install-script
          # ...
```

But then you'd want to cache apt litter alongside pnpm's, so you should check https://stackoverflow.com/a/72959639/11715259 out.

Comment: Not working. issue is same

Comment: Error message is still about missing `libcurl.so.4` specifically?